# How to add,remove div or span in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website and in one of the webpages in the websites,i want to add or remove span element(can be div element also) in the webpage according to data fetched from the website.

Here is the code:

**HTML PART:**

```
<html>  
<span class="t1"><input type="text" class="t1" id="t1s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
</span>   <span id="star1s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating1"></span>   
<hr>                            
<span class="t2"><input type="text" class="t2" id="t2s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
</span>   <span id="star2s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating2"></span>   
<hr>                            
<span class="t3"><input type="text" class="t3" id="t3s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
</span>   <span id="star3s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating3"></span>   
<hr>                            
<span class="t4"><input type="text" class="t4" id="t4s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
</span>   <span id="star4s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating4"></span>   
<hr>                            
</html>
```

In the html part,span part should be added or removed according to data fetched from database.
Below is the code i need to add or remove,

```
 <span class="t4"><input type="text" class="t4" id="t4s<?php the_ID(); ?>">
</span>   <span id="star4s<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="rating4"></span>   
<hr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT PART:**

```
<script>
var getstarid = "<?php the_ID();?>";

function rating1( stars1 ) {
var ratingfill1=stars1;
var rating_integer1=Math.floor(ratingfill1);
var rating_decimal1=ratingfill1%1;
var rating_dec_trimmed1=rating_decimal1.toFixed(1);  
if((rating_dec_trimmed1==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.2)||
(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.4))
{document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer1)+18) + 'px';}
if((rating_dec_trimmed1==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.7)||
(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.9))
{document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer1)+28) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed1==0.5)
{document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer1)+20) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed1==0)
{document.getElementById("star1s"+getstarid).style.width = 
(40*rating_integer1) + 'px';}
 }

function rating2( stars2 ) {
var ratingfill2=stars2;
var rating_integer2=Math.floor(ratingfill2);
var rating_decimal2=ratingfill2%1;
var rating_dec_trimmed2=rating_decimal2.toFixed(1);  
if((rating_dec_trimmed2==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.2)||
(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.4))
{document.getElementById("star2s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer2)+18) + 'px';}
if((rating_dec_trimmed2==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.7)||
(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.9))
{document.getElementById("star2s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer2)+28) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed2==0.5)
{document.getElementById("star2s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer2)+20) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed2==0)
{document.getElementById("star2s"+getstarid).style.width = 
(40*rating_integer2) + 'px';}
 }

function rating3( stars3 ) {
var ratingfill3=stars3;
var rating_integer3=Math.floor(ratingfill3);
var rating_decimal3=ratingfill3%1;
var rating_dec_trimmed3=rating_decimal3.toFixed(1);  
if((rating_dec_trimmed3==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.2)||
(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.4))
{document.getElementById("star3s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer3)+18) + 'px';}
if((rating_dec_trimmed3==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.7)||
(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.9))
{document.getElementById("star3s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer3)+28) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed3==0.5)
{document.getElementById("star3s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer3)+20) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed3==0)
{document.getElementById("star3s"+getstarid).style.width = 
(40*rating_integer3) + 'px';}
 }

function rating4( stars4 ) {
var ratingfill4=stars4;
var rating_integer4=Math.floor(ratingfill4);
var rating_decimal4=ratingfill4%1;
var rating_dec_trimmed4=rating_decimal4.toFixed(1);  
if((rating_dec_trimmed4==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.2)||
(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.4))
{document.getElementById("star4s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer4)+18) + 'px';}
if((rating_dec_trimmed4==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.7)||
(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.9))
{document.getElementById("star4s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer4)+28) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed4==0.5)
{document.getElementById("star4s"+getstarid).style.width = 
((40*rating_integer4)+20) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed4==0)
{document.getElementById("star4s"+getstarid).style.width = 
(40*rating_integer4) + 'px';}
 }

var second=0,third=0,fourth=0;

var getrate1 = "<?php echo $ratingonequery;?>";
var getrate2 = "<?php echo $ratingtwoquery;?>";
var getrate3 = "<?php echo $ratingthreequery;?>";
var getrate4 = "<?php echo $ratingfourquery;?>";
var getratename1 = "<?php echo $ratingnameonequery; ?>";
var getratename2 = "<?php echo $ratingnametwoquery; ?>";
var getratename3 = "<?php echo $ratingnamethreequery; ?>";
var getratename4 = "<?php echo $ratingnamefourquery; ?>";


 //below is part of javascript that serves as the logic for adding or 
 //removing span element
if((getrate1!="")&&(getratename1!=""))
{rating1(getrate1);document.getElementById("t1s"+getstarid).value 
 =getratename1;}

{
if((getrate2!="")&&(getratename2!="")){second=1;
rating2(getrate2);document.getElementById("t2s"+getstarid).value 
=getratename2;
}
 else if((getrate3!="")&&(getratename3!="")){third=1;
 rating2(getrate3);document.getElementById("t2s"+getstarid).value 
 =getratename3;
        }
 else if((getrate4!="")&&(getratename4!="")){fourth=1;
 rating2(getrate4);document.getElementById("t2s"+getstarid).value 
 =getratename4;
        }           
  }

  {
  if((getrate3!="")&&(getratename3!="")&&(third==0)){third=1;
  rating3(getrate3);document.getElementById("t3s"+getstarid).value 
  =getratename3;
   }
  else if((getrate4!="")&&(getratename4!="")&&(fourth==0)){fourth=1;
  rating3(getrate4);document.getElementById("t3s"+getstarid).value 
  =getratename4;
        }
   }

  if((getrate4!="")&&(getratename4!="")&&(fourth==0)){fourth=1;
  rating4(getrate4);document.getElementById("t4s"+getstarid).value 
  =getratename4;
  } 
 document.getElementById("t1s"+getstarid).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("t2s"+getstarid).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("t3s"+getstarid).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("t4s"+getstarid).disabled = true;
 </script>
```

**CSS PART:**

```
<style>
.rating1,.rating2,.rating3,.rating4 {
font-size: 48px;
color: #0095f9;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}
 .rating1::before { 
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
 }
 .rating2::before { 
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
  }
  .rating3::before { 
   content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
   }
   .rating4::before { 
    content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
    }
   .t1,.t2,.t3,.t4{background-color:#ffffff;
    float:left;font-size:20px;
    padding: -3px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #0095f9;
    outline: none;
     }
 </style>
```

I have also included screenshot.
[image: Screenshot of the output]

So,how to add or remove span element in html part by logic in the javascript part.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: How to add html: `$("selectorwheretogo").append("html to add")`  How to remove html `$("selectortoremove").remove()`.   Not sure what the 100s of lines of code have to do with this... perhaps you could review this [mcve]

Comment: I will tell you a secret: your code is not readable and I can bet there will not many people who will be willing to try to read it. Basic formatting, indents and spaces would help.

Comment: If you start using "counters" in variable names, that is a clear sign you should use an array instead. And if you are using them in function names, for functions that all basically do the exact same thing, just on other objects/with different values, that is a clear sign that you should go learn how to write functions _properly_, without that much repetition, and using parameters in eligible places instead.

Comment: Google MDN `createElement`, `appendChild`, `removeChild`. Usage example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/kopmjm1d/

Comment: This question boils down to, how to add and remove HTML elements. I know you are new and most of us asked somilar questions when we were new.

Answer (score 0):

You should read w3schools for proper what is and how to :
 
for javascript : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

for jquery : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

You will find removechild and remove() in these pages too.

You can also read the MDN docs for more thorough understanding of the topic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#del").on('click',function(){
    $("#delete").remove();
  })
  $("#add").on('click',function(){
    $("#hello").append("<br><span id='added'>I got added</span><br>");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<span id='hello'>Hello</span><br>
<span id='delete'> I will get deleted</span><br>

<input type="button" id='del' value='Delete span'><br>
<input type="button" id="add" value='Add span'>
</div>
```